# The identifier is not supported in the current command usage. You specified 'testname'

Tags: iis, iis-7, application-pool, appcmd

While trying to create an application pool via [appcmd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731784(v=ws.10).aspx)

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd add apppool /name: testname /managedRuntimeVe
rsion: -v4.0 /managedPipelineMode: -Integrated
```

i get the folowing error

```
The identifier is not supported in the current command usage. You specified 'testname'.
```

So, what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brilliant.

Removed the extra space character from **/name: testname** to **/name:testname**
and it just works.